# Is it possible have the scopes in JWT Token without put allowed scopes in the deployment.toml file?

Tags: wso2

I need to secure my wso2 api with scopes.
However, to have scopes in JWT token at login,
I must insert these scopes in **[apim.oauth_config]** section of **deployment.toml** file,
with the key **allowed_scopes**.
The problem is that for every new scope, I need to do this operation.
Is there another way?

Comment: In the token call, do you specify scopes? In that case you should get those scopes in the JWT.

Comment: Yes, I do, but If I don't put scopes into deployment.toml, in output token there aren't scopes.

Comment: When generating an access token you can specify the required scopes. If the user has relevant roles, then the user gets that token. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/oauth2/oauth2-scopes/fine-grained-access-control-with-oauth-scopes/#obtaining-tokens-with-scopes